# Exception: Access violation writing location when using strcpy_s

Tags: c, strcpy

When I compile the following code, I get this exception:

Unhandled exception at 0x0FA8E90F (ucrtbased.dll) in console.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFCD

```
 void test()
{
      char *type = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
      strcpy_s(*type, 7,"Laptop");
}
```

I have to mention that I am a begginer in working with dynamic implementation and pointers. I am also not allowed to use a static implementation.

In the above snippet I also tried different implementations as: replacing the following line:

```
  strcpy_s(*type, 7,"Laptop");
```

with this line:

```
  strcpy(*type, "Laptop");
```

but the result was the same. Any suggestion for my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These kinds of typos can often be caught by the compiler.  Make sure you're not suppressing or ignoring warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `strcpy_s(*type, 7,"Laptop");` you want `strcpy_s(type, 7,"Laptop");`

`strcpy_s` assumes the first argument is a pointer for the destination of the data, as per the signature: `errno_t strcpy_s(_CHAR *_DEST, size_t _SIZE, const _CHAR *_SRC)`.

In your code you were dereferencing the pointer `type` when passing it to `strcpy_s`, which is the problem. Because the function expects a `char *` as the first argument, when you pass `*type` instead of `type`, it is as if you passed a `char` which is then incorrectly interpreted as a pointer (memory location). When `strcpy_s` tries to write to this invalid memory location, it throws the access violation exception you see. Note this is the same reason `strcpy` was giving you the same result.

Comment: That's worked for that exception. I modified the code, but when I tried to compile it again, this time I got this exception at the same line: 
                                                                                            
console.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Comment: @PhyllisVance are you using visual studio to compile this? a breakpoint is not an exception, its a way to pause the code on a given line when debugging.